# Creating Summaries By Different Combinations Of Grouped Factors And Across All Factors

Tags: r, dataframe, summary, summarize

apologies if something similar has been asked before

I'm looking to see if there is a more straightforward way to create multiple aggregated summaries for different combinations of factors. Ideally, I want to produce a dataset that summarises a numerical variable for each combination of levels within 4 or more factors, and also to have additional rows that provide an 'All' level for each factor which thereby summarises across the entire factor.

To begin with, similar to the example below, I have a dataset with 4 factors with 2 or more levels, and a numerical variable that is measured across these combinations.

```
# Create Example Dataset
my_dataset <- data.frame(Machine = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 10),
       Operator = rep(c("X", "Y"), 15), 
       Location = c(rep("Location 1", 10), rep("Location 2", 10), rep("Location 3", 10)),
       Technique = rep(c("Technique E", "Technique F"), 15), 
       Errors = round(rnorm(30, mean = 12, sd = 2)))
```

So far I'm able to get sum for each of the individual combinations of the levels within these factors. For example, using the code below I can get the sum of Errors from Machine A, with Operator B, at Location 1, using Technique 1, ... and so on...

```
# Create Summaries for Each Group Combination
Individual_Summary_Data <- my_dataset %>%
  group_by(Machine, Operator, Location, Technique) %>%
  summarise(Errors = sum(Errors), .groups = "keep")%>%
  mutate(Summary_Type = "Individual Summary")
```

The difficulty I'm having is that I also want to create summaries across all levels from these factors. For example, using the code below I can see the sum of Errors for each Machine across All Operators, All Locations, and All Techniques

```
# Create Aggregate Summaries Across All Levels of Groups

# Create Container for Aggregated Summaries
Aggregated_Summaries <- list()

# 1 Factor Summaries
# Summaries at Machine Level only
Aggregated_Summaries$Machine_Summary <- my_dataset %>%
  group_by(Machine)%>%
  summarise(Errors = sum(Errors))%>%
  mutate(Operator = "All", Location = "All", Technique = "All", Summary_Type = "Grouped Summary")
```

Using similar blocks of code, I can also get similar aggregates for each Operator, each Location, and each Technique. However, this becomes more complicated if I want to summarise across all levels of multiple factors. For example, in the code below I can get the sum of errors for each Machine and each Operator across all Locations when using all Techniques:

```
# 2 Factor Summaries
# Summaries at Machine and Operator Levels only
Aggregated_Summaries$Machine_Operator_Summary <- my_dataset %>%
  group_by(Machine, Operator)%>%
  summarise(Errors = sum(Errors))%>%
  mutate(Location = "All", Technique = "All", Summary_Type = "Grouped Summary")
```

I would then repeat this block of code for each potential pairing of the 4 factors, and then do the same across each potential combination for 3 factors (and so on if dealing with more than 4 factors).

Essentially, I can already create summaries across each factor, and for each permutation of these factors by repeatedly copying the blocks of code above. However, my current approach introduces a lot of repetition to the code, and becomes more and more complicated as the number of factors increases. Ideally, I'm looking for a solution which would reduce the need to repeatedly copy similar blocks of code, particularly if it can then be scaled up to handle 5,6,7+ factors with less repetition.

Open to any advice or feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach hope it does help you :

```
my_df <- data.frame(Machine = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 10),
                Operator = rep(c("X", "Y"), 15), 
                Location = c(rep("Location 1", 10), rep("Location 2", 10), rep("Location 3", 10)),
                Technique = rep(c("Technique E", "Technique F"), 15), 
                Errors = round(rnorm(30, mean = 12, sd = 2)),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_f <- function(x, my_data) {
  my_temp <- my_data %>% group_by(my_data[, x]) %>% summarise(Errors = sum(Errors))
  return (my_temp)
}
my_machine <- my_f("Machine", "Errors", my_df)
my_operator <- my_f("Operator", "Errors", my_df)
my_test <- my_f(c("Machine", "Operator"), "Errors", my_df)
```

The aim is to create a function that does what we want, you give it the column you want to group and then the dataframe